# C - C_Holt-Winters function called within R Holt-Winters function

Tags: c, r, holtwinters

I am trying to understand the C function which is called in the R Holt-Winters function.

The section by which I am confused reads:

```
     for (i = *start_time - 1; i < *xl; i++) { 
56         /* indices for period i */ 
57         i0 = i - *start_time + 2; 
58         s0 = i0 + *period - 1; 
59 

60         /* forecast *for* period i */ 
61         xhat = level[i0 - 1] + (*beta > 0 ? trend[i0 - 1] : 0); 
62         stmp = *gamma > 0 ? season[s0 - *period] : (*seasonal != 1); 
63         if (*seasonal == 1) 
64             xhat += stmp; 
65         else 
66             xhat *= stmp;
```

This reads as though, if "t" is 13 and there are 12 seasonal periods (i.e. "period" is 12), then i0 would be 1 and s0 would be 12.  stmp would then take a value which was based on the "season" value from time (s0-12), which in this case would be time 0.  But this doesn't make sense, since the seasonality component in the Holt-Winters model is from (in this case), 12 periods previously.

I would be grateful if someone could explain what i0 and s0 actually are, and where I have failed in my understanding of this.

Full code:

https://github.com/pierre/holt-winters/blob/master/holt-winters.c

Comment: The first time through the loop (which seems to be what you are talking about), `i0` will be 1 as you say, but `s0` will be 12, not 13. (1 + period - 1), so that is one mistake.

Comment: You could replicate this in base R that way you could easily see what is going on with print statements and what not.  Just keep in mind, everything you see here is base 0.

Comment: Yes @Gregor, you are correct - I meant 12.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to keep in mind that HW needs initial values for components **level**, **trend** and **season**, inserted in positions **level[0]**, **trend[0]** and **season[0]**...**season[period-1]**. It is important to note that initial *season* component is a vector with *period* elements.

The HoltWinters function begins estimating the **i**th value of the time series, then it computes next values of **level**, **trend** and **season**. The variable **i0** corresponds to next empty position in vectors **trend** and **level**, and variable **s0** corresponds to next empty position in vector **season**.

In first iteration, i0 and s0 are assigned the following values:

```
i0=1
s0=period
```

From second iteration and on, they get incremented by one, just like **i0++** and **s0++**. Their way of updating these variables seems confusing because it is done in function of variable **i**, but it is for a good reason: statements are the same in all iterations, including the first.